# I don't know how to solve $\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x) = -3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have no idea how to solve this equation $\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x) = -3$. I've tried to use the formulas for $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and for $\sin(3x) =  3\sin(x) - 4\sin^{3}(x)$, but all for nothing.

Comment: Just to be clear, we are not considering complex values of $x$, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that to attain $-3$, we require

$$\sin(x)=\sin(2x)=\sin(3x)=-1$$

I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: But this doesn't correspond to a real solution, does it?

Comment: there is no real solution.

Comment: yeah, no real solution

Comment: Right.  $x, 2x$ and $3x$ must all be $-\frac \pi 2$ plus or minus some multiple of $2\pi$ and that is easily verified as impossible.  (If $x$ is $-\frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$ then $2x = -\pi + 4k\pi$ which is not $-\frac \pi$ plus or minus some multiple of $2\pi$).  Or if we want to be formal, if $\sin x = -1$ then $\sin 2x= 2\sin x\cos x = 2\times -1\times 0$ and $\sin 3x = 3\sin x-4\sin^3(x) = -3+4 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue the expansions, let $\sin(x)=t$ and you end with
$$-4 t^3+2 t\sqrt{1-t^2} +4 t=-3$$ After squaring processes, you need to find the roots of
$$16t^6-28t^4-24t^3+12t^2+24t+9=0$$ which cannot be solved (in fact, no real root at all).

Numerically, the solutions are $$t=-0.635632 \pm 0.219414\,i\implies x=-0.608034\pm 0.177981\,i$$

There would be solution if, in absolute value, $\text{rhs} < 2.49960$.